# How to solve the equation $x^2 + 4 |x| - 4 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I get the value of x from the equation that is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting $x=a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real

we get $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=4-(a+ib)^2=4+b^2-a^2-2abi$

Equating the imaginary parts $ b=0$

Now for real $x,$ 
$$|x|= \begin{cases} +x &\mbox{if } x\ge0 \\
-x & \mbox{if } x<0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: The answer given is $\pm(\sqrt8 - 2)$

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's distracting you from how to solve the problem. Use the suggestion below $y=|x|$ and work with that. Once you have the solutions for $y$ see what $x$ values will meet that

Comment: @DannyDan, can we assume $x$ is real?

Comment: If you do not assume $x$ is real, why do you assume it is complex? May be $x$ is an octinion or matrix of even operator on Hilbert space.

Comment: @Norbert, Can you please elaborate via example?

Comment: No$\phantom{} $

Answer (score 8):

Hint:
$$
x^2=|x|^2
$$
${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Put $y=|x|$. Then you have $y^2 + 4y-4 = 0$.  Now can you solve and see if you get any solutions for $y$ and then $x$?

Comment: Yea this becomes quite clearly a quadratic equation which can be solved easily

Comment: Yes.  In essence it's just clarifying what Norbert hinted earlier.

Comment: Then how do I get $x$ once I have $y$?

Comment: You can always find two values for x, as long as y is positive. Try it.  If negative, no solution for x.